# WS_MINIMIZE flag added by itself

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-studio-2012

I am experiencing a very bizarre bug with creating window on Windows OS.
I am creating window with following part of code.
This window is a plugin in another application, so I creating a window as a child inside window provided by other application.

```
newWindow = ::CreateWindow("SomeName",
    "",
    WS_CLIPCHILDREN | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
    in_create_options._location.m_x,
    in_create_options._location.m_y,
    in_create_options._size.m_x,
    in_create_options._size.m_y,
    (HWND)in_create_options._parent,
    0,
    0,
    newView);
```

But when the window is activated it also has WS_MINIMIZE flag, therefore activated minimized. The problem is, it only happens in RELEASE mode, therefore I can not debug it.
What I want to ask is - does someone know what may cause this?
In addition, is there any way I can check and update windows flags before activate it?

P.S. I tried this code:

```
WINDOWINFO currentWindowInfo;
::GetWindowInfo(((WCPluginViewWin *)in_view)->m_nativeView, &currentWindowInfo);
if (currentWindowInfo.dwStyle & WS_MINIMIZE)
{
    currentWindowInfo.dwStyle &= ~WS_MINIMIZE;
    ::AdjustWindowRect(&currentWindowInfo.rcClient, 
}
::ShowWindowAsync(((WCPluginViewWin *)in_view)->m_nativeView, SW_SHOW);
```

but it still does not work. Window still opens with WS_MINIMIZE flag.
Is there something else instead AdjustWindowRect?

Comment: Actually it is ",". Thanks. But it is not missing in original code :)

Comment: How are you running your release application? Perhaps you're running it from a shortcut that has start minimised set in its properties?

Comment: Sure that you posted the correct one? A `WS_CHILD` window can certainly not be minimized, how would that work? It only lives inside another window.

Comment: Maybe it is not related, but you should add the actual `hInstance` of you module as the next-to-last argument, instead of `0`.

Comment: There are few parts in Windows that have had more appcompat hacks than the window style flags.  But you certainly need to expect this to behave strangely, making a window a child of another window that doesn't belong to the same thread is completely illegal.  It was okay in Windows 3.x, the only possible reason that it works at all.  What actually will happen is a wild guess to me, I suppose you found out.  You need to drop WS_CHILD and in_create_options._parent and explicitly call SetParent() instead to have any hope of getting somewhere.

Comment: Why did you decide it is from another thread? In any case, using SetParent instead of WS_CHILD flag does not help.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue.

::ShowWindowAsync(((WCPluginViewWin *)in_view)->m_nativeView, **SW_SHOW**);

needs to be changed to

::ShowWindowAsync(((WCPluginViewWin *)in_view)->m_nativeView, **SW_SHOWNORMAL**);